# Не могу понять, почему конструктор exception выдает ошибку

Tags: c++

почему не получается кинуть exception c помощью вот такой записи  `throw std::exception("Com port not found");`, насколько я знаю, в нем должен быть конструктор принимающий строку. Выдаетэту ошибку

> ошибка: no matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'const
>   char [19]' to 'std::exception'

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/exception то наверное `std::runtime_error`

Comment: Стандартная версия не имеет такого конструктора(имеется в производных классах), однако в версии Microsoft   этот конструктор есть.  В моем приложении, к примеру, это нормально работает,